# Customise Receipts How to?

Tags: receipts, printing

In Find contributions> actions: receipts print or email> how would I customise that wording / graphics for that choice

Answer (score 5):

Try under **Administer > Communications > Message Templates**. From there you can look in "System Workflow Messages" for the receipt templates.

[More about templates is in the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates/#modifying-system-workflow-message-templates).

[image: System Workflow Messages - screenshot.]